# postgresql to_timestamp returns different date than represented by the timestamp

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql

Here's a replication of the problem:

I get the timestamp of now via JavaScript as

```
var ts = +new Date // 1368971991090
console.log( new Date(1368971991090) ); // Sun May 19 2013 13:59:51 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Then in my Postgres console,

```
# select to_timestamp(1368971991090);
          to_timestamp          
--------------------------------
 45350-12-30 05:31:29.999872+00
(1 row)
```

A date way too much into the future.
[The docs of JavaScript `Date#getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) say it returns milliseconds starting from the epoch; same as the [argument type Postgres' `to_timestamp` accepts](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-formatting.html). Java's `Date#getTime` returns same value as JS `Date#getTime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote from postgresql doc from your link:

> it accepts a double precision argument and converts from Unix epoch
>   (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00) to timestamp with time zone.

Key -

> seconds since

And in JS doc:

> number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC

Comment: Well put. JS is rather unusual in counting in milliseconds; generally speaking "Unix timestamp" means number of *seconds* since 1970, possibly with a decimal or floating point representation for fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps anyone, but I ran into the same issue recently. The solution was to convert the JS timestamp to seconds since the epoch, instead of milliseconds.

```
const millisecondsSinceEpoch = Date.now();
// output: 1631828038018
const secondsSinceEpoch = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
// output: 1631829225
```

In Postgres:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1631828038018);
// output: 53680-07-27 14:06:57.999872

SELECT to_timestamp(1631829225);
// output: 2021-09-16 22:53:45+01
```